# ASP.NET Core 3.0 Web API - controller method not hit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I am new to ASP.NET Core Web API - this is my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Createnewlead")]
public IActionResult LeadCreate([FromBody]CRM_Lead Lead)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

This is my json:

```
{
   "RegionID": "1",
   "RunningNo": "1633",
   "CardName": "Google Pte Limited",
   "Telephone": "65748394",
   "Mobile": "89349859",
   "Fax": "47850555",
   "Email": "sre@hotmail.com",
   "ROC": "28IO45h44",
   "OwnerEmail": "huisan@syspex.com"
}
```

[image]

Please advise me!

Comment: Try https://localhost:5001/Createnewlead instead of https://localhost:5001/api/sap/createnewlead or change your route to [Route("api/sap/Createnewlead")]

Comment: There is an open source project I saw that might be useful - https://github.com/ardalis/AspNetCoreRouteDebugger

Comment: Agree with @AndreLombaard -- you're hardicoding the route / path to your Action with your `Route` attribute.

Comment: you need to show  your model/startup/error messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your route to

```
[Route("api/[Controller]/Createnewlead")]
```

Your route is currently set to `[Route("Createnewlead")]` which will translate to route `https://localhost:5001/createnewlead` but you are calling `https://localhost:5001/api/sap/createnewlead`

or alternatively, post to

```
 localhost:5001/Createnewlead
```

In your example, you are setting a route per action, instead you can also set a route per Controller, for example

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class MyController: Controller 
{
}
```

or

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class MyController: Controller 
{
}
```

or

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MyController: Controller 
{
}
```

It all depends on what you want your routing to look like

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce your problem (400 error and not hit the controller) in asp.net core 3.0 web api using below model(which defines  `RegionID` as `int` instead of `string`):

```
public class CRM_Lead
{
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    public string CardName { get; set; }
    //other properties
}
```

It is caused by the default `System.Text.Json` in asp.net core 3.0.

**Solution1:**
Change your post json to remove `""` on the properties whose types are `int`

```
{
   "RegionID": 1,//instead of "1"
    ....
}
```

**Solution2:** Keep your above json and use old `Newtonsoft.Json` in an ASP.NET Core 3.0 project by referencing [Json.NET support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#newtonsoftjson-jsonnet-support).

1) `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson -Version 3.0.0`

2) Add `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson()`; in startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

Check Ur Routing Attribute and Postman / Browser URL, both are totally different

Your Route attribute has no route "api/sap/Createnewlead" it has only "Createnewlead".

Change ur routing attribute url with ur desired url

Answer (score 0):

I'm using asp.net core 6.0 with Angular and when I follow the documentation for [conventional routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cr6) with multiple controllers I do not for some reason get the expected behavior- the api call does not hit the endpoint, but when I follow the [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#ar6) documentation I get the expected behavior.